# Would changes be visible to a different thread if synchronizing using different objects?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, locking

Imagine this piece of code inside the class. We are trying to change `val` value in different threads calling `method1` and `method2`, respectively.

Is it expected that changes made to `val` would be visible in another thread, if we are using different objects to synchronize on? And what would be a good test case to design?

```
private Object lock1 = new Object();
private Object lock2 = new Object();
private int val = 0;

public void method1 () {
    synchronized (lock1) {
       System.out.println(val);
       val = 1;
    }
}

public void method2 () {
    synchronized (lock2) {
       System.out.println(val);
       val = 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably not. Testing visibility is tricky since you need to ensure that the change has actually happened (= happens-before relation) to see whether you can read the correct value but at the same time that it's not guaranteed to be visible (= not happens-before).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no happens-before relation between acquiring and releasing different monitors, so there is no guarantee when changes will be visible.

Comment: if `val` is volotile then it would be?

Comment: yes but since threads run in parallel, value can be examined before it is changed, which has the same effect as if changes are not visible immediately. You have to use some ordering mechanism (like blocking queues).